# Learning DB2 - Need Help to Start

Tags: db2

I would like to learn DB2 as my work is demanding these skills now... I have prior programming knowledge but that is limited to VBscripting and Jscripting

I am complete new to the DataBase segment.. I have no clue of SQL or Oracle or DB2 and stuffs....

Can Someone please mentor me here ... So that I get fair Idea on where to Start and how to accomplish my Goals...

Appreciate your quick help.

Thanks 
Jey B

Answer (score 2):

Visit [DB2 University](http://www.db2university.com/). Some of their courses are free, although I don't see any right now. You can download a [free version of DB2](http://www.db2university.com/web/download/index.php). You can also [download several textbooks](http://www.db2university.com/web/resources/index.php). *Database Fundamentals* might be a good place to start.

I don't think any of their downloads require registration, but I could be wrong about that.

Edit: I was wrong about that. Textbooks don't seem to require registration, but DB2 Express-C does and the development tools do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... Is there any prerequisites for learning DB2 like understanding of Database or RDBMS or something like that.....

Comment: You need some very basic computer skills. (You have to install software.) You don't need to know a programming language first. The text _Database Fundamentals_ is a good, free introduction, but it's a technical book. You might do better if you can find a similar book in your first language.

Comment: Now that I've thought more about it, I guess you could look at _Database Fundamentals_ as a prerequisite. The book _Getting Started with DB2 Express-C_ teaches you how you can use DB2 to implement the databases described in _Database Fundamentals_. (Loosely speaking.)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Fundamentals of Relational Database Design](http://www.deeptraining.com/litwin/dbdesign/FundamentalsOfRelationalDatabaseDesign.aspx) for some information on the best way to design databases.  You may not be doing any design at the moment, but understanding these basics is key!

Also, [Understanding SQL Joins](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Understanding-SQL-Joins/) is mandatory reading if you are going to be writing queries.

DB2 does have some language specific exceptions when writing queries that you will just have to learn as you go.  For instance, most DBs use the TOP command:

```
SELECT TOP 3....
```

to get just the first 3 records.
DB2 requires this syntax at the end of the query:

```
FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY
```